# How to get RTF format of images and texts in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have a RichTextBox and I want to enter texts and images into it and transfer the contents to another RichTextBox, I also have another RichTextBox and a Button that call the below line when clicked
`richtextbox2.rtf = richtextbox1.rtf;`
but only texts are pasted into richtextbox2, images are not. If I can get RTF format of the images I can do
`richtextbox2.rtf = @"{\rtf{\ltrch {*\shppict{\pict\picwgoal2685\pichgoal945\pngblip 89504e470...";`
and it displays the image, but the rtf format I used is from the Internet, I don't know how to create it from the contents of the richtextbox1

**Question: How to get the full RTF format that includes all texts and images from a RichTextBox**

Purpose: To paste it to another RichTextBox and still display the same contents
Why: Because I have to transfer the contents of the richtextbox1 over the internet to reach the richtextbox2
Here is my code to produce this problem

```
            var richtextbox1 = new RichTextBox();
            richtextbox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
            richtextbox1.WordWrap = false;
            richtextbox1.ContentsResized += new ContentsResizedEventHandler(richTextBox_ContentsResized);
            richtextbox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
            richtextbox1.MaximumSize = new Size(2000, 2000);

            var richtextbox2 = new RichTextBox();
            richtextbox2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
            richtextbox2.ReadOnly = true;
            richtextbox2.WordWrap = false;
            richtextbox2.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
            richtextbox2.ContentsResized += new ContentsResizedEventHandler(richTextBox_ContentsResized);
            richtextbox2.MaximumSize = new Size(2000, 2000);

            var btn = new Button();
            btn.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            btn.Click += (s, e) => {
                richtextbox2.Rtf = richtextbox1.Rtf;
            };
            form.Controls.Add(richtextbox1);
            form.Controls.Add(btn);
            form.Controls.Add(richtextbox2);
            Application.Run(form);
```

And here is the result when clicking the button
[image: Result]
the image in the left richtextbox isn't transfered to the right richtextbox

Comment: Usually, the RTF contains whatever you have inserted in the RichTextBox. Post the code used to paste / insert the Images and the .Net version in use. Also, please explain what this means: *Purpose: To paste it to another RichTextBox and still display the same contents*. Do you want to set the source RTF to another control or are you trying to paste the content? Two quite different things.

Comment: @Jimi I type to the richtextbox using keyboard and the texts are in the RTF but the images I paste with Ctrl+V are not, and I'm trying to paste the content

Comment: Yes, of course the image bytes are serialized in the RTF. What .Net version are you using? Also, as mentioned, explain what *To paste it to another RichTextBox [...]* means, in the context of the operations you're trying perform.

Comment: @Jimi I simply want the second richtextbox to have the same content that the first richtextbox has by editing its .RTF property. But the RTF property of the first richtextbox only contains the texts even after I pasted the image and I don't know why. I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @Jimi I just edited my question to describe my problem more clearly

Comment: Remove `richtextbox2.ReadOnly = true;` from where it is now and, if needed, add it after `richtextbox2.Rtf = richtextbox1.Rtf;`